# Styling &raquo; inside span

Tags: html, css

Say I have a span that looks like this:

```
<span> This is my string &raquo;  and it continues </span>
```

And I want the font color of what is inside that span to be black, except for the  » that I want it to be red.

What would be a good way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best HTML/CSS way is

```
<span> This is my string <span>&raquo;</span> and it continues </span>
```

and style your inner `<span>` as you wish

```css
span { color: #000 }
span span { color: #c00 }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Wrap it up with another `<span>` tag.

The best way is to wrap it up with another `<span>` tag this way:

```
<span> This is my string <span class="r">&raquo;</span>  and it continues </span>
```

And give style this way:

```
span span.r {color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the `&raquo;` in another element and styling that.

**html:**

```
<span> This is my string <em>&raquo;</em> and it continues</span>
```

**css:**

```
span { color: #000000; }
span em { color: #ff0000; font-style: normal; }
```

Comment: Why abuse the `<em>` here? `<em>` is a *semantic* element denoting emphasis. That doesn’t sound like what OP wants, especially since you normally give emphasis to content, not typography.

Comment: The OP didn't give context so the <em> might be perfectly appropriate - we don't have enough information to judge your accusation of abuse. The more common mistake I see in HTML is using <span> and <div> instead of appropriate semantic elements.

Comment: Using a different colour is emphasis, is it not? I could have used `<strong>` here too just as easily but went with the shorter tag.